# Как удалить дубликаты из массива не зависимо от их регистра?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив вида

```
["А","а","а","А","и","И"]
```

Нужно удалить дубликаты и оставить только уникальное значение независимо от регистра

```
["А","и"]
```

C учетом регистра делаю так

```
array.filter((v, i, s) => v && s.indexOf(v) === i)
```

Как попроще сделать без учета регистра?

Comment: использовать ``.toLowerCase()``. Или ``.toUpperCase()``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как и написал в комментариях  *Эникейщик* надо использовать одно из двух `toLowerCase()`  или `toUpperCase()`

```js
const arr = ["А","а","а","А","и","И"];

const a =  arr.reduce((result, element) => {
    const normalize = (x) => typeof x === 'string' ? x.toLowerCase() : x;

    const normalizedElement = normalize(element);
    if (result.every(otherElement => normalize(otherElement) !== normalizedElement))
      result.push(element);

    return result;
  }, []);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Попроще без учета регистра:

```
array.map(_=>_.toUpperCase()).filter((v, i, s) => v && s.indexOf(v) === i);
```

Правда в зависимости от реализации чейнов браузером можем получить два полных прохода по одному массиву.

Comment: Реализация хороша, но не подходит потому что нужно создать массив из исходных данных, а тут приводим все в верхний регистр =)

Answer (score 2):

[localCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) позволяет сравнивать без учета регистра.

Пример кода:

```
const arr = ["А","а","C","c","а","А","и","И"];

const isEqual = a => b => a.localeCompare(b, [], {sensitivity: 'base'}) === 0;

const result = arr.reduce((acc, x) => acc.some(isEqual(x)) ? acc : [...acc, x], []);
```

Comment: Супер! Жаль нельзя выбрать больше одного ответа...

Answer (score 1):

Приводим все к одному регистру и создаем из массива set:

```js
var data = ["А","а","а","А","и","И"];
var data = data.map(function(x){ return x.toUpperCase() });
var filtered_data = new Set(data);

for (var elem of filtered_data ) {
    console.log(elem)
}
```

Comment: Любопытно конечно, но что с производительностью? Можно еще записать одной строчкой: `Array.from(new Set(array.map(_=>_.toUpperCase())))`. Думаю автору вопроса такая запись по душе будет.

Comment: Неясно, критично ли это для автора вопроса, но здесь результат `['А', 'И']` отличается регистром от приведенного в вопросе - `['А', 'и']`.

Comment: @Yaant Автору регистр как раз и неважен.

Comment: Ну, я скорее склоняюсь интерпретировать формулировку вопроса как "вернуть первое уникальное значение, следующие, отличающиеся только регистром, игнорировать". И при таком прочтении, то, что массив `['a', 'b', 'c']` превратится в `['A', 'B', 'C']` (которых в исходном массиве вовсе нет), меня лично смущает :)

Comment: @Yaant При таком прочтении не подойдет мое решение, конечно.

Comment: Вот я и говорю, неясно, что же на самом деле имелось в виду. Поэтому я и оставил комментарий, чтоб обратить внимание на возможный подводный камень. :)

Comment: Регистр является критичным, но все равно спасибо за версию =)